# merge array and increase int value when key match in php?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

how do I merge two arrays, and just increase the values when the keys match?
Both the arrays might contain keys that does not exists in the other, and both of them might have more or less keys than the other.

So I cannot just take one array, and loop trough that and compare with the other since some times the "other" array might have more values. This swithces from time to time.

Array merge doesn't seem to be working either since it overwrites the old value.

I need to return all unique keys from both arrays, but but whenever a key matches, I need to just add the two values together.

**Array_a:**

```
["BMW-B2"]=>int(1)
["BMW-N-115 "]=>int(5)
["BMW-N-143"]=>int(3)
["BMW-N-163"]=>int(10)
["BMW-N-184"]=>int(4)
```

**Array_b**

```
["CR220036"]=>int(3)
["BMW-N-163"]=>int(9)
["CR220822"]=>int(7)
```

**Array_merged**

```
["BMW-B2"]=>int(1)
["CR220036"]=>int(3)
["CR220822"]=>int(7)
["BMW-N-115 "]=>int(5)
["BMW-N-143"]=>int(3)
["BMW-N-163"]=>int(19)  //  <--  this has increast by 9
["BMW-N-184"]=>int(4)
```

The order is not important.

Comment: write the simplest example of input, output and result of what you want, or -even better- a unit test, you'll make life easier for everyone including yourself

Comment: Okei. I've added an example of two arrays, and what I need as an output

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a loop *and* and merging the arrays.  Basically, you pick one array that you will check for duplicate values, perform your arithmetic, `unset` the no longer needed array elements, and then merge it all together.

Consider adapting your code similar to the following:

```
$array1 = array("val1" => 5, "val2" => 8, "val3" => 10, "val4" => 2, "val5" => 12);
$array2 = array("val3" => 9, "val6" => 11, "val1" => 15);

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array1))
    {
        $array1[$key] += $value;
        unset($array2[$key]);
    }
}

$merged = array_merge($array1, $array2);

var_dump($merged);

//Output:
array(6) {
  ["val1"]=>
  int(20)
  ["val2"]=>
  int(8)
  ["val3"]=>
  int(19)
  ["val4"]=>
  int(2)
  ["val5"]=>
  int(12)
  ["val6"]=>
  int(11)
}
```

In my example, all the values in `$array2` are compared with `$array1` to locate duplicate keys and increment by the stored value.  If a dupe is found then that element is unset, this will prevent the modified keys in `$array1` from being overwritten in the `array_merge()` operation.

Comment: Thank's. I'll have a look at it on monday, and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$arr1=array(1,2,3,4);
$arr2=array(1,2,5=>1);
$result=array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    $result[$k]=$v;
    if(isset($arr2[$k])){
        $result[$k]+=$arr2[$k];
    }
}
foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v){
   if(!isset($result[$k]){
      $result[$k]=$v;
   }
}
var_dump($result);
```